# How to edit Ansible with default fail condition and customer fail condition

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible function, like

```
- shell: ...
  register: results
  failed_when: (default fail condition) or ("upgrade false" in results.stdout)
```

How do I fill `(default fail condition)`? Then this function is able to fail on **normal fail condition** and fail on **customer condition** (results contains string "upgrade false")

Answer (score 1):

The default fail condition is simply fail on any exit code other than `0`. You can do the same like this:

```
- shell: ...
  register: results
  failed_when: (results.rc > 0) or ("upgrade false" in results.stdout)
```

Comment: I haven't worked a ton with failure conditions. I'll test that later